# Broken stop button on Vista SP2 Media Center, any ideas when this will be fixed?

Tags: windows-media-center

Well in one of the SP1 media center rollups, MS managed to break the stop button.

Try:

- Play bear.
- Press stop - video pauses (frame freezes) there is no OSD
- Press play - video plays
- Press stop - the screen pops up with all the stop options (delete etc.)

This has been acknowledged as an issue by MS: http://discuss.mediacentersandbox.com/forums/thread/9254.aspx

Does anyone have any inside information as to when this is going to get fixed?

Answer (score 1):

No inside info, but [they have a workaround](http://thegreenbutton.com/forums/p/72503/377553.aspx#377553):

> I've identified the buggy component to
>   be ehplayer.dll.
>
> Firstly, you need to take ownership of
>   ehplayer.dll in C:\Windows\ehome: 1)
>   Open an elevated command prompt (i.e.
>   right-click on Command Prompt and
>   choose Run As Administrator 2) Go to
>   C:\Windows\ehome 3) Type: takeown /f
>   ehplayer.dll cacls ehplayer.dll /G
>   :F (so on my system it is
>   cacls ehplayer.dll /G HTPC\cdldt:F)
>
> Now you have access to ehplayer you
>   can replace it. The version you need
>   (18000) can be downloaded from here:
>   http://www.quantexzone.com/files/ehplayer_18000.zip
>   I have no intention of infecting
>   anyone's PC with malicious software,
>   but if you don't trust me you can get
>   this from your side-by-side directory.
>   Go into C:\Windows\winsxs and search
>   for ehplayer. You should see several
>   versions of ehplayer.dll listed. One
>   of them should be build 18000 (you can
>   tell from the directory name).
>
> Back in C:\Windows\ehome, rename
>   ehplayer.dll to ehplayer.old and then
>   copy the 'new' version (i.e. build
>   18000) into C:\Windows\ehome.

Comment: This looks interesting, but is not something I could recommend to my customers, I am fairly sure the workaround is not supported by MS

Comment: True.  Then Diago's answer (official channels) may be the best way to get reliable info about this.

Answer (score 0):

The best possible way to get some inside information would be to report the problem on [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com) for your particular operating system, which should provide you with a response from the Microsoft Engineering team. Although they will acknowledge issues on public forums, solutions and information are generally provided through connect. I would guess the problem will most likely be resolved in the next Service Pack if they have already acknowledged it.